# Do MDB messages get lost if a node in a cluster containing the MDB dies?

Tags: jboss, jgroups

I have a cluster of JBoss servers (using JGroups and Infinispan) which have a bunch of MDBs which communicate with each other.

I have two cases, one where I send frequent messages between my MDBs and when I shutdown a node I'm not sure if any of the messages should be lost, or if my configuration is bad and I lose these messages.

In the other case I send about 10 messages every 5 seconds, and if I shutdown a node the "lost" MDBs are reconstructed on other nodes and no messages are lost.

I'm having a hard time testing the behavior of these messages when I shutdown a node, so I was wondering if someone can give me a quick answer. Should the messages be lost or is my configuration to blame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using persistent delivery for your messages, they should not be lost.  Not persistent messages may be lost on a broker restart.